# How to use TNetEncoding.URL.Encode for encoding spaces in query string parameters?

Tags: delphi, encoding, delphi-xe7

In Delphi XE7 it is advised to use TNetEncoding.URL.Encode

So far I have been using a custom routine:

```
class function THttp.UrlEncode(const S: string; const InQueryString: Boolean): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := EmptyStr;
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    case S[i] of
    // The NoConversion set contains characters as specificed in RFC 1738 and
    // should not be modified unless the standard changes.
    'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '*', '@', '.', '_', '-', '0'..'9', 
    '$', '!', '''', '(', ')':
       Result := Result + S[i];
    '—': Result := Result + '%E2%80%94';
    ' ' :
      if InQueryString then
        Result := Result + '+'
      else
        Result := Result + '%20';
   else
     Result := Result + '%' + System.SysUtils.IntToHex(Ord(S[i]), 2);
   end;
end;
```

Using the method above I have been able to manually specify whether the encoded parameter S is a part of the Path or a part of the Query string.

The spaces should be encoded as + if found in the Path and as %20 is part of the Query parameters.

The function above emits properly

```
Url := 'http://something/?q=' + THttp.UrlEncode('koko jambo', true);
// Url := http://something/?q=koko%20jambo
```

but the following is returning different value

```
Url := 'http://something/?q=' + TNetEncoding.URL.Encode('koko jambo;);
// Url := http://something/?q=koko+jambo
```

Please elaborate in what way TNetEncoding.URL.Encode should be properly used for encoding query parameters containing spaces as %20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation:

[System.NetEncoding.TURLEncoding](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.NetEncoding.TURLEncoding)

> **TURLEncoding only encodes spaces (as plus signs: +)** and the following reserved URL encoding characters: ;:&=+,/?%#[].

It is not possible to make `TNetEncoding.URL.Encode` encode spaces as `%20`.

Normally, I would suggest Indy's `TIdURI` class, as it has separate `PathEncode()` and `ParamsEncode()` methods, but they both encode spaces as `%20` as well, which does not satisfy your "encoded as + if found in the Path" requirement.

Comment: The last paragraph reads a little strangely. "Normally, I would suggest...., but they encode spaces as `%20` as well". Isn't encoding spaces as `%20` exactly what is wanted? Or did you write `%20` by mistake and meant ``+``?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: read the OP's requirement: "The spaces should be encoded as + if found in the Path and as %20 is part of the Query parameters."

Comment: Last part of your answer says, " but they both encode spaces as %20 as well". Isn't that what's wanted. Or is the problem that PathEncode() and ParamsEncode() encode spaces as %20 for spaces in both url and query?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The latter.

Comment: Just a note many years after. What you are talking about here is the difference between URL encoding and URI encoding. In JS, URI encoding is done via EncodeURIComponent which has an extended range of characters it encodes. Also, source character encoding must be taken height for (UTF8, 16, asci, misc iso).